# Difference in time between two dates in java

Tags: java

I have to find the difference in time between two different date objects in java and if that time exceeds 5 sec i have to invalidate the session.

Here's the scenario :

I have a jsp page which set the session every 5 sec

```
session.setAttribute( "sessionAccessedAt", new Date() );
```

I have a another jsp page which is accessed every 1 sec ,

```
Date date2 = new Date();
```

Now i have to compare in the another jsp that i have mentioned and invalidate the session,

```
Date date1 = (Date)session.getAttribute("sessionAccessedAt");
Date date2 = new Date();

Differnce = date2 - date1;
```

Thereby if the difference exceeds 5 sec, invalidating the session.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
   long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    // now you have your answer in milliseconds - 
//so divide by 1000 to get the time in seconds
```

Answer (score 9):

```
if ((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) > 5000) { // getTime returns the time in milliseconds
    // invalidate
}
```

But the session timeout is supposed to be handled by the container, not by you.

PS : this is easily answered by reading the javadoc : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html

Answer (score 9):

Building on the other answers, `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` makes it very easy to convert between milliseconds, seconds, etc...

```
 long differenceInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
```

Answer (score 4):

From Java-8 onwards you may use-

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate.toInstant(), endDate.toInstant());
```

This is a generic Enum using which, it becomes pretty simple to find difference in any Unit.