# how to find the total time taken for a process in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

i have two java date time values and i want to know the total time taken for the process.

```
private static Date crawlStartDate,crawlEndDate,totalCrawlTime;
```

how can i get that? time format is yyyyMMddhhmmss

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in time between two dates in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911387/difference-in-time-between-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: I would use joda time for this anyhow

Comment: Sooo many duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this one..

```
   public static void main(String[] argv) {

    long lStartTime = new Date().getTime(); // start time

    createArray(); // some tasks to eat time

    long lEndTime = new Date().getTime(); // end time

    long difference = lEndTime - lStartTime; // check different

    System.out.println("Elapsed milliseconds: " + difference);

}

public static void createArray() {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String sArray[] = new String[1000000];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        sArray[i] = "Array " + i;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java solution:

```
long d1=crawlStartDate.getTime()
long d2=crawlEndDate.getTime()
long diff = d2 - d1;
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;  
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
```

If you work in Linux/BSD use `time java MyJavaProcess` . `time` here is [unix utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_%28Unix%29). For example I can measure some process in this way:

```
$ time java Hello
One value
Two value

real    0m0.070s
user    0m0.068s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 0):

Get time before process execution

```
long t1=crawlStartDate.getTime()
```

Get time after process execution

```
long t2=crawlEndDate.getTime()
```

and then calculate difference

```
long timeDiff=t2-t1;

Date date=new Date(timeDiff);
```

and format it using SimpleDateFormat-

```
DateFormat formatet = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

String formattedDate= formater.format(date);
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the "then calculate difference" part.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
     String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
    String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    try {
     d1= format.parse(dateStart);
     d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
     long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
     long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
     System.out.print("Days:" + diffDays);
    }catch(Exception e ) {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  long differenceInSec = (crawlEndDate.getTime() - crawlEndDate.getTime())/1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have updated to JAVA8 then try the below code

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2014, 06, 27, 15, 12);
        LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.now();

        int diffInNano = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2)
                .getNano();
        long diffInSeconds = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2)
                .getSeconds();

        long diffInMilli = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2)
                .toMillis();
        long diffInMinutes = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2)
                .toMinutes();
        long diffInHours = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime, dateTime2)
                .toHours();
        System.out.println(diffInNano);
        System.out.println(diffInSeconds);
        System.out.println(diffInMilli);
        System.out.println(diffInMinutes);
        System.out.println(diffInHours);
```